# Bash script does not execute in CRON (might be to do with Sudo commands?)

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu, cron, pg-dump

I have a bash script that uses ssh tunneling to get a PSQL dump remotely then puts the dump into a local MySQL database.

I can't seem to get CRON to run it.

I have performed the following steps:

1) Ran:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

2) Input the following to get the script to execute every 10 minutes.  Script also takes about 2-3 minutes to execute fully.

```
*/10 * * * * /home/ubuntu/psqlimport 2>&1 /home/ubuntu/cronlog.log
```

3) Ran:

```
sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/psqlimport
```

4) Restarted CRON:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart
```

I check my database to see if there were any updates and there are none, as if the script never executed.  There is also no /home/ubuntu/cronlog.log file created.  When I run:

```
bash psqlimport
```

The script executes as expected.

Why doesn't the CRON job execute the script?

Filename: psqlimport

```
#!bin/bash

###
#
# PostgreSQL to MySQL Dump  program
#
# Filename: psqlimport
# Description: This program dumps the 3 tables from a
# remote PostgreSQL database, converts the dump file
# into MySQL translatable INSERT INTO queries,
# and inputs the data into the local
#  MySQL Inbevdash6 database.
#
# Script can be copied to the
# /etc/cron.daily folder for daily database updates.
#
#
# Script written by ramabrahma@stackoverflow
# Date: December 15, 2015
# Version: 01
#


#Set the dump file and temp file
DUMPFILE='psql.dump.sql' || (echo "assign var failed" 1>&2; exit 1)
TMPFILE=`mktemp` || (echo "mktemp failed" 1>&2; exit 1)

#Tables to dump: table1, table2, table3
#Dump as INSERT queries statements


sudo -E sshpass -p "<remote host password>" \
ssh username@remote_host \
pg_dump -U database_username -t table1 \
 -t table2 -t table3 \
 --column-inserts --data-only psqldatabase \
 | awk '/^INSERT/ {i=1} /^SELECT/ {i=0} i' \
 > "$TMPFILE" \
 || (echo "pg_dump failed" 1>&2; exit 1)


#Adding transaction blocks to the dump file
(echo "start transaction; truncate table table1; "; \
echo "truncate table table2; "; \
echo "truncate table table3; "; \
cat "$TMPFILE"; echo 'commit;' ) \
 > "$DUMPFILE" \
 || (echo "parsing dump file failed" 1>&2; exit 1)

#Inputting the dump file to the MySQL database
mysql --defaults-file="/home/ubuntu/.mysql.db.cfg" < "$DUMPFILE" \
  || (echo "mysql failed" 1>&2; exit 1)

#Remove the temp file created
rm "$TMPFILE"
rm "$DUMPFILE"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29):

```
#!bin/bash
```

It should be

```
#!/bin/bash
```

`bin/bash` probably isn't a path to anything unless you're executing out of `/`. This wasn't a problem when you executed the script manually as `bash psqlimport` explicitly invokes `bash` to evaluate the script. You'll be able to see the problem in action if you try to run `./psqlimport` to run the script.